# Is booting from an NVMe SSD possible on all motherboards without the UEFI BIOS?

Tags: boot, ssd, motherboard, pci-express, nvme

Can I boot with an NVMe SSD on an ASUS P5G41C-lX-M Motherboard which doesn't use the UEFI BIOS? BTW I am using an M.2 to PCIe 1x adapter to connect it to the mother board.

I just wanted to know if it would work.

Comment: If I helped, please mark my answer as the answer by clicking on the green tick. @digiprox

Answer (score 1):

A legacy BIOS won't be able to recognise the drive as a storage component and will lack the compatibility of looking there for an OS to boot from, so you need to use a drive recognised by your BIOS to hold the boot manager.